# extract date from string format timestamp using python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

convert Sun Feb 07 15:12:22 IST 2021 to 07/02

I am unable to read this data using timestamp/datetime library

I have tried :

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = Sun Feb 07 14:58:52 IST 2021
dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%d-%m-%y') 
  
print("date:",dt_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does this by first parsing the date string into a datetime object, and then using that object to format the required date string. I've included comments explaining each of the date string formatters used - one note; %Z (for the timezone) will only recognise IST as a valid timezone if IST appears in time.tzname for your machine's locale, otherwise it will throw an exception. If you are struggling with this, you could always just replace IST with something universal (GMT or UTC) in the date string before calling strptime.

```
import datetime 
import time

datestr = "Sun Feb 07 15:12:22 IST 2021"
# %a is day of week, eg Sun
# %b is abbrev month, eg Feb
# %d is zero-padded day of monthe, eg 07
# %H:%M:%S is 24-hour time hh:mm:ss
# %Z is timezone name - NB IST will need to be in time.tzname for your locale
# %Y is 4-digit year
dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
print(dateobj.strftime("%d/%m"))
```

Comment: If IST isn't in your timezone, you could make the code work by doing this:

datestr = datestr.replace("IST", "GMT")

before all the comments. It should work just fine as long as you aren't doing date arithmetic across timezones - but better to sort out the timezone properly.

Comment: Don't just replace `IST` with `GMT`;-) Have a look at [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) - here, you can supply a mapping dict that maps an abbreviation like `IST` to a IANA time zone name, e.g. `Asia/Kolkata`.